# Power Function in Java

Tags: java

> Given a number and its reverse. Find that number raised to the power of its own reverse.
> Note: As answers can be very large, print the result modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.

```
class Solution
{
        
    long power(int N,int R)
    {
        if(R==0){
            return 1%1000000007;
        }
        else if(R%2==0){
            return power((N*N)%1000000007,R/2)%1000000007;
        }
        return (N%1000000007)*power((N*N)%1000000007,R/2)%1000000007;
    }
   
}
```

When I run this program for 12 raised to power 21 it returns 0.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: By using `BigInteger`. (or maybe `long` is enough)

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Comment: Do I have to find something or do the calculation here? I have X and Y given and I have to do X^Y haven't I ?

Comment: @StephenC *that* math really does not matter since OP uses a lot of mod operations already meaning that the max value they deal with will be 1000000006*1000000006 which fits into a `long` afaik but not in an `int`.